# Нужно сделать так,чтобы можно было передавать в функцию и статическую, и динамическую матрицы(си)

Tags: c, матрицы

Есть такое определение функции

```
void input(int **matrix, int n, int m)
```

Но оно работает только для динамических матриц. Как можно было бы изменить,чтобы работало и для статических и динамических? Или что можно сделать со статической матрицой но притом,чтобы она оставалась статической.

Comment: начнем с того, что Си язык очень простой и понятия "матрицы" нем нет. есть только массивы, "статический" массив от "динамического" отличается только временем жизни и местоположением в памяти приложения. т.е. в стеке он или в куче. в остальном для вашей функции разницы с каким указателем с памяти работать абсолютно нет разницы. просто укажите правильные значения м и н у  статического массива при вызове вашей функции.

Comment: ну попробуйте привести статическую матрицу к динамической `input((int**)matrix, 10, 20)`

Comment: int matrix[5][5]; и int* matrix = (int*)malloc(5*5); в памяти сформируют 25 ячеек, только одна будет в стеке, а вторая в куче.

Comment: @Zhihar, у нас в тегах был вопрос про С, вы привели код на С++, фактически любая "матрица" конечном итоге есть просто указатель на массив байт в памяти, как правило, этот указатель стараются делать в одном участке памяти, что есть простой одномерный массив нужной длинны, к примеру M*N. если уж на то пошло то и std::vector можно считать одномерной динамической матрицей 1*N

Comment: Храните вашу матрицу в одномерном массиве размера `m * n`. В функцию передавайте указатель на первый элемент массива `int* matrix`. К i-той строке j-тому столбцу обращайтесь `matrix[i * количество_столбцов + j];`

Comment: @Yakov, судя по всему ТС формирует свою матрицу так: `int** matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int*)); for (int i = 0; i < n; ++ i) matrix[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));` Ни о каких идущих подряд n * m ячейках речи не идёт.

Comment: По заданию у меня есть статическая и две динамические матрицы, одна динамическая задается как массив длиной n*m и массив длиной n из указателей на начало каждой строки,а вторая как три массива длиной m и массив из указателей на начало каждого массива. В обоих случаях они имеют тип указатель на указатель. И для всех трех матриц должна работать одна и та же функции ввода @Yakov

Comment: @Yakov, не понял - а где я код на C++ привел? В C нельзя такое приведение типов было делать?

Comment: Если сильно не хочется изменять вашу функцию `input`, то можно сделать массив указателей на первые элементы строк статической матрицы, и уже этот массив передавать в функцию, но это какой-то костыльный способ)

Comment: ну в чем беда сделать указатель на статический массив? сделай еще один массив и в него запиши базовый адрес + n, m-раз. я к тому, что одним вызовом выделить 100 байт памяти или 10ю вызовами выделать 10 байт памяти результат будет один. а как ее уже логически разбивать это уже не столь важно.

Comment: @atsterk, формально ваша функция вводит не матрицу, а `n` одномерных массивов (каждый из `m` элементов), получая массив указателей на первые элементы этих массивов. Соответственно, **вызывающая программа** должна обеспечить этот интерфейс. Т.е. для ввода  "статической" матрицы она должна выделить и инициализировать адресами строк такой матрицы массив, который и передается в `input()`

Comment: @atsterk Дополните вопрос как инициализируются матрицы

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать подделку. Динамическую матрицу, указывающую на строки статической.

```
// $ gcc -Wall -std=c11 -Wextra -Wpedantic dynmat.c -o dynmat && ./dynmat
void input(int **matrix, int n, int m) {
  matrix[3][3] = 777 ;
  }

# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>  
  
int main(){
  int n = 7 ;
  int m = 8 ;
  int static_matr [n][m];
  static_matr[3][3] = 888 ;
  printf("0. static_matr[3][3] = %d\n",static_matr[3][3]);
  
  int * * dynamic_matr = malloc ( sizeof (int * ) * n ) ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++ i )
    dynamic_matr [ i ] = static_matr [ i ] ;

  input ( dynamic_matr , n , m ) ;

  free ( dynamic_matr ) ;

  printf("1. static_matr[3][3] = %d\n",static_matr[3][3]);          

}
```

Проверка :

```
0. static_matr[3][3] = 888
1. static_matr[3][3] = 777
```

Дополнительную память будет занимать чуть больше `n*m+n` вместо `n*m`. И установка указателей на статическую матрицу займёт мало времени `n`.